# The integral of x is not the same as $x e^{- k x}$ if k goes to $0$ .

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, parametric

I have this problem, I don't know why if I consider:

$k \geq 0$

$ I(k)= \int x e^{-k x}= - \dfrac{e^{-kx}(kx+1)}{k^2}$, with integration constant $c=0$.

If I put ${lim}_{k \to 0}  I(k) {\to -\infty} $.

On the other hand, before doing the integral $I(0) \equiv \int x \equiv \dfrac{x^2}{2}$

You don't find the same situation in $I(k)=x^2 + k x$ .

Please could you tell me why the first integral diverges ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some confusion about the calculations here, so I'm going to answer an analogous question. $I(r) =\int x^r =\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}$, except for $r=-1$; $I(-1)=\log(x)$. So the question arises why $I(r)$ does not tend to $I(-1)$ as $r\to-1$. After all, $x^r\to x^{-1}$ uniformly on compact sets.

One way to look at  it is you're forgetting the "$+c$", or maybe better,  you chose the $c$'s in the integrals in such a way as to make things discontinuous.

> > **Exercise:** Find constants $c_r$ so that if $I(r)$ is as above then $I(r)+c_r\to I(-1)$ as $r\to-1$.

(Hint: Consider $x=1$.)

(Or one could put it this way: An antiderivative is actually an element of  a quotient space consisting of functions modulo constants. We *do* have $I(r)\to I(-1)$ *in* that quotient space)

Or we could just note that the problem goes away if we consider *definite* integrals: If $$J_r(x)=\int_1^x t^r\,dt$$ then uniform convergence shows we *can* take the limit inside the  integral; $J_r$ depends continuously on $r$.

Comment: Yes, I put a specific integration constant (I should have mentioned it). In addition definite integral simplifies the problem.

Comment: This is to add to the answer: You want to show that for all fixed $y$, the quantity
$\frac{e^{-kx}(kx+1)}{k^2}|_{x=y} - \frac{e^{-kx}(kx+1)}{k^2}|_{x=0}$ goes to $y^2/2$ as $k$ goes to 0.

Comment: ....It is as the answer is above, taking *definite* integrals. But note that there is a $k^{2}$ term in the denominator in the above. So you have to approximate $e^{-kx}$ to $1-kx+k^2x^2/2 + o(k^3x^3)$ for taking limits to be valid, as the 1 and the "$kx$' terms should cancel out but the quadratic term will still contribute in the limit